# NodeJS. How to access the directory name of the js file from a module which is being used in that js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I m creating an api.

Soo my API Structure is like

```
<myapi_folder>
  |
  ---index.js
  ---package.json
  ---<utils_folder>
         |
         ---load.js
```

Now let work.js is a file which is located somewhere on my system.
The code of

### work.js

```
const myapp = require("myapi_folder");
```

The point is i want to know the directory location of work.js in load.js program.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does `work.js` interact with `load.js`? I assume that worker.js require 'myapi_folder', and 'myapi_folder/index.js' called 'load.js'?

There are two possible ways.

1 - Explicitly pass __dirname of caller to callee. In your case:

```
    // myapi_folder/index.js
    function load(callerDir) {
       require('./load').do(callerDir);
    }

    // worker.js
    var api = require('myapi_folder');
    api.load(__dirname);
```

2- Use `callsite`, this is hacky and not recommended for this case.

```
   // myapi_folder/index.js
   var callsite = require('callsite');
   function load() {
      var callerDir = callsite()[1].getFileName();
      require('./load').do(callerDir);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

We use the [approot module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/approot) and it works very well.

This is at the top of most of our node modules:

```
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
var logger = require(appRoot + '/services/logger');
var cache = require(appRoot + '/services/cache');
```